# Maintaining individual folder structure with Mercurial

Tags: mercurial

We have a main repository of code, separated into subfolders such as SQL, Websites, etc. We are looking to add an additional folder for our SSIS Packages and similar items so that we can keep backups. However, they are stored in folder structures external from our code repository in three separate servers. We need to maintain the original folder structure on these servers containing the SSIS packages.

Normally I would put Mercurial on each of machines hosting files that were to be added to the repository, pull down a copy of our repo, and add the files to the repo. However, in this case I won't be able to move the files into the repo folder after I pull down a copy, because the directory structure needs to be maintained.

The only alternative I can think of is to create a second repository for the SSIS packages, but this still runs into the issue that there are three servers with SSIS files to be added, all with their own unique folder structure. Which means that we would have to either change the directory structure of the three servers to match each other, or create three separate repositories.

Please note that the goal here is not for "installing" these files to the servers - the files are already on the intended servers and are (rarely) modified locally when required - it's purely for backing up the versions and maintaining a minimal number of mercurial repositories.

**Is it possible to maintain a unique individual folder structure on a local machine while committing files to Mercurial?**

An example folder structure was requested in the comments:

Current Repo structure:

- Repo

  - Documentation
  - Reports
  - SQL
  - Applications

    - Application A
    - Application B

The goal is to add a new folder so it will look like this:

- Repo

  - Documentation
  - SSIS

    - Server 1
    - Server 2
  - Reports

However, each server stores the files in different directory structures (directly dropped in the base C drive, one in a separate sub directory, and the third deep in a legacy Visual Source Safe directory), and is referenced externally so changing them to match the repo is sub optimal.

Hence the question - is there a way to add files to a mercurial repo without dropping them into a pulled copy of the repo?

Comment: Are the files the same on the 3 machines, just stored in a different folder structure?

Comment: No, they are all different files. But they are of the same type, so they should be sorted into the same folder in the repository ideally, possibly with a subfolder indicating which server they came from.

Comment: IMHO, If the logical structure of the repo doesn't make the logical structure of the deployment, you need an install tool. Makefiles are the old school version, but you need something. Attempting to make your version control tool an install tool always ends in tears.

Comment: Perhaps you could post a couple example directory structures, and what you expect the resulting Mercurial repository to look like, so we can see exactly what you mean? As is what you're describing sounds like madness.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, what you're trying to do doesn't sound like a great idea to me. I think you can do what you want to do using symlinks in the file system.

Mercurial knows how to manage symbolic links, and you could make a tree of symbolic links for each machine pointing back to the real files in a different
tree.

So, it's possible, but it seems like a very error prone process to me. I think
you're far better off using an install tool and putting the "Makefile" or rake tasks, or ... in your repo.